# Codeigniter: Insert string if set_value() is empty

Tags: codeigniter, setvalue

I understand that `set_value()` is used to populate a form should it fail vaidation. But if the field is `empty()` (which is why it failed) can set_value() insert a default value instead?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. It involves intercepting the value in `set_rules()` using 2 callback functions. I stripped the code down for this post so it's easier to understand.

**The config file:**

```
// This is where the default text will come from so it's easy to modify
// The second config (['address']) is there just to show that ['test'] is an array
$config['test']['name'] = 'Default Text';
$config['test']['address'] = 'Some other text';
```

**The Rules:**

```
// The sample rule. Do not add 'required' in the rules since _sanitize already
// does the checking for blank values. Insert the name of the field
// within the []. _sanitize() needs to be called before _check().
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|callback__sanitize[name]|callback__check[name]');
```

**The 2 callback functions: _sanitize() and _check()**

```
// CALLBACK: _sanitize
/*
* If field is empty(), inserts the default value found in the config file
* Works alongside _check().
*/
public function _sanitize($str, $arg){
  if(empty($str)){
    $text = $this->config->item('test');
    return $text[$arg];
  }

  // If !empty(), return the value as if nothing happened
  return $str;
}

// CALLBACK: _check
/*
* If value is equivalent to the default value (from the config file), mark it as FALSE
* Works alongside _sanitize().
*/
public function _check($str, $arg){
  $text = $this->config->item('test');

  if($str == $text[$arg]){
    $this->form_validation->set_message('_check', 'The %s field is required');
    return FALSE;
  }

  return TRUE;
}
```

**Lastly, the code for the View:**

```
// Put at top of page
<?php
$name = array(
    'name'=>'name',
    'value'=>set_value('name'),
    'class'=>"form-text",
    'maxlength'=>200
);
?>

// Put within the page
<?php echo form_input($name); ?>
```